# How best to export from Oracle Ent Ed (EE) to Oracle Express Edition (XE)?

Tags: oracle, import, export

I am aware that Oracle Ent Ed (EE) has more functionality than Oracle Express Ed (XE).  But I would like to do a FULL export from EE to XE.  Is this even possible?  The only solution I can assume will work would be to export/import tablespaces or schemas.

A comment was made that this question was not precise so let me clarify (hopefully):

EE has features that XE does not have.  It follows that EE may have schemas that XE does not have or use.  When the import is done, will the import fail in XE because those 'extra non-XE' schemas are not recognized due to the absence of the feature in XE?  Or will XE just 'not fail, not care'?

NOTE: I was hoping to do a FULL export which is why I am concerned about the schemas being different between EE and XE.

HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a full export and always import just the schemas you want from the dump.

Personally, I'd just export the schemas I was interested in, assuming it's not hundreds. - [user10361](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10361/colin-t-hart)